# Centos-release update package

Tags: centos, cloud, upgrade

during my usual packages upgrade routine a new package appeared on the list of the ones that should be updated: **centos-release (6-4.el6.centos.10).** I would like to know if this installs a new kernel as my Cloud provider excluded from the yum.conf file the kernel upgrades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this installs the new EL6.4 kernel version - **2.6.32-358.0.1.el6** and newer.

CentOS follows the Red Hat release cycle. The minor version of CentOS was bumped from version 6.3 to 6.4 last week.

`yum update` and `yum upgrade` would both push you to version 6.4 at this point.

Comment: My current version is Centos 6.3 final, should I use yum upgrade or yum update? What's the difference?

Comment: I think you are wrong. CentOS-release does not update the kernel. the kernel RPM updates the kernel

Comment: The release updates the target OS revision. The OS revision dictates the kernel version. If the question is whether an update from EL 6.3 to EL6.4 includes a kernel upgrade, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

No that particular RPM just updates certain files for the 6.4 version of CentOS

```
#repoquery -l centos-release

/etc/centos-release
/etc/issue
/etc/issue.net
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-6
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Security-6
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-6
/etc/redhat-release
/etc/rpm/macros.dist
/etc/system-release
/etc/system-release-cpe
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo
/usr/share/doc/centos-release-6
/usr/share/doc/centos-release-6/EULA
/usr/share/doc/centos-release-6/GPL
/usr/share/doc/redhat-release
```

the kernel is a different RPM